# ASP.NET. Custom Page on 401

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

I have a webpage(home.aspx) that requires Windows Authentication. If the browser automatically sends in valid credentials, then home.aspx is displayed. Otherwise, login.aspx is displayed.

In IE, I have checked off the "Prompt for User name and Password" checkbox in Internet Options > Local Intranet > Custom level > User Authentication. 
I have following the steps in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11202/Redirecting-to-custom-page-when-quot-Access-de , and it works fine on my local development server. However, on the production server, it is a different story.

In IIS, Home.aspx has anonymous authentication disabled, and windows authentication enabled. Login.aspx has anonymous authentication enabled and windows authentication disabled.

In the development server, on a computer that is logged in using correct credentials, home.aspx shows up. And, when the browser does not send in the credentials, Application_EndRequest is hit with a 401 status code, then the default Windows Authentication Prompt shows[image]. 
After cancelling this dialog, login.aspx is shown. This is the correct behavior.

However, in production server, on a computer that is logged in using correct credentials, home.aspx shows up. And, when the browser does not send in the credentials, Application_EndRequest is hit with a 401 status code, then the default Windows Authentication Prompt shows. After cancelling this dialog, the default 401 page shows.[image]

Does anyone what is going on the production server, and why I am not able to intercept the 401 status code and redirect to a custom web page.

Comment: I don't have sample code in front of me to post as an example, but it sounds like you need to allow anonymous access to login.aspx from your web.config or security settings. Otherwise, IIS won't serve it without valid credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I enabled anonymous access to login.aspx, and disabled windows authentication, and still get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS 7, they added an attribute in web.config that controls the behavior of custom errors. By default, custom and detailed errors are only shown on the local browser. To show your custom errors, you need to change this in the web.config `<httpErrors>` element, `errorMode` attribute.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultResponseMode="File" >
         <remove statusCode="500" />
         <error statusCode="500"
            prefixLanguageFilePath="C:\Contoso\Content\errors"
            path="500.htm" />
       </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

`DetailedLocalOnly` is the default; other possible values are `Detailed` and `Custom`.

For more reading, here is the [Microsoft article](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors) that talks about this configuration.

*Aside*: The article you linked is more than 10 years old, and is therefore quite suspect for "modern" development. One of the comments on the article, posted about 5 years later, points to this same problem and solution.

Comment: I have set the errorMode to Detailed, and now, it doesn't redirect to login.aspx. However, it shows an empty page for home.aspx. When I viewed source in IE, this was the entire content: <script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='login.aspx'; </script>. It is as off the javascript code is not being hit at all.